# Battery - reconditioning a 12V UPS lead acid battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have a 12V lead acid battery UPS battery which I want to revive.

I tried adding baking soda to clean it internally but it did not work. I also tried distilled water in the battery but it was also not helpful.

It reads only 1.30V on my multimeter.

Will a desulfating battery charger using a 555 or other desulfating circuit work (in my case) or any other method?

I am beginner in this and I need some advice.

Comment: What is your question? Adding baking soda to a 12V battery will mess up the chemistry and probably ruin it. I hope you know what you're doing.

Comment: Even if desulphating does work, it won't recover all or even most of the capacity. Really it would be better to recycle it and get a new one.

Comment: I want to know recommended process to recover 12V lead acid UPS battery.I need some advice on this